# Eliminate presence of String1 from String2

Tags: php, string

I have $String1 which I know has the value 999 and  is 3 digits and starts at pos 7 in $String2.

```
$String1 = 999;  
$String2 = 789992399987;
```

I would like to eliminate $String1 from $String2, to create $String3

```
$String3 = 789992387;
```

I don't think I can use strstr, because as in this case 999 appears 0,1 or more times before the string I want to eliminate

My current work around is the unelegant way of making $String2 an array and because I know the position and length of $String1 unset those keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove a substring from a string by position and length, you can use [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php).

```
$String3 = substr_replace($String2, '', 7, 3);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/ttQhvA

Comment: somehow i didnt know substr_replace existed

Comment: @Galen I find that PHP has a function for everything. I once implemented something that converted an IP string to a 64bit integer, and lo and behold, someone pointed to me [`ip2long`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php).

Comment: I'd recommend str_ireplace (case insensitive).

Comment: Thanks, i overlooked substr_replace because i wasn't 'replacing' but I am, I'm replacing it with nothing. Nice one.

Comment: @DigitalPrecision The OP mentioned he cannot use a text replace function.

Comment: @Xeon06: What is substr_replace()?

Comment: @DigitalPrecision a substring replacement function. There is no case sensitivity as there is no text search.

Comment: the str_irreplace won't help me but may help a future problem. Meanwhile would there be an opposite function - like string input?

Comment: @AdamNarbutt I'm not sure I understand, what kind of opposite function?

Comment: Sorry a bit cheeky, adding String1 to String3 to MAKE string2.

Comment: FOund answer, sorry     www.tizag.com/phpT/php-string-substr_replace.php

Comment: @AdamNarbutt ah, you can also use `substr_replace` for that, just put in a `0` for the `length` parameter. http://codepad.viper-7.com/ucPitl